# Node.js, Javascript: node-debug won't detect Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging

```
$ node-debug -p 8082 try-debug.js 8081
Node Inspector is now available from http://127.0.0.1:8082/?ws=127.0.0.1:8082&port=5858
Debugging `try-debug.js`

No browser matching [chrome,chromium,opera] found in the system!
```

Google Chrome is present as the default browser.

It just might be relevant, I'm not sure:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/lodash/collection/detect.js
module.exports = require('./find');
$
```

Comment: _"Google Chrome is present as the default browser."_ Does `node.js` search  working directory, or entire filesystem ?

Comment: I cannot tell. Where am I supposed to look?

Comment: chrome should be installed in `/usr/bin/` by default ; though `~/.cache` may also contain a file name "google-chrome" . Not certain about `node.js`, though if can run `cat` at `terminal` should be able to check using something like `$ find /usr/bin/google-chrome` or `$ find ~/.cache/google-chrome`

Comment: It is /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable. There is also ~/.cache/google-chrome directory